# Create .bat to execute XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibLaTeX

Tags: xetex, compiling, automation

Time ago I created a bat script to execute PDFLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibLaTeX so I can add as a processing tool in TeXworks (image below), and it was easy because I found many sites explaining how to do that manually.

[image]

The script is the following:

```
miktex-pdftex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=pdflatex "%1"
biber.exe "%2"
makeindex -t "%2".glg -s "%2".ist -o "%2".gls "%2".glo
makeindex -t "%2".alg -s "%2".ist -o "%2".acr "%2".acn
makeindex -t "%2".nlg -s "%2".ist -o "%2".not "%2".ntn
miktex-pdftex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=pdflatex "%1"
```

with arguments **$fullname** and **$basename**

But now that I want to do the same but with XeLaTeX I can't find any information to do so.

Where can I find this information? or How do I achieve this?

I wonder that I must use xetex.exe, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to use it.

[image]

Comment: It's not the point of your question, but you may be interested in `arara`: https://ctan.org/pkg/arara

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think it was pretty easy, Im not really sure if it's the proper way but it seems to work.

After executing `miktex-xetex.exe --help` if found it has the same commands as `miktex-pdftex.exe --help` so I assumed the functionality is the same, and changing **pdftex** to **xetex** and **pdflatex** to **xelatex** did the work

```
miktex-xetex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=xelatex "%1"
biber.exe "%2"
makeindex -t "%2".glg -s "%2".ist -o "%2".gls "%2".glo
makeindex -t "%2".alg -s "%2".ist -o "%2".acr "%2".acn
makeindex -t "%2".nlg -s "%2".ist -o "%2".not "%2".ntn
miktex-xetex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=xelatex "%1"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `.bat` (I assumed that you are using `MicroSoft`) file with a name what you likes, e.g., if the .bat file will be as `test.bat`

Then, open it into any of the editor, e.g., `Notepad`, `EMacs`, `Epsilon`, etc.

```
call xelatex %1

call bibtex %1

call xelatex %1

call xelatex %1

call makeindex %1

call xelatex %1
```

You should place the `.bat` file into your current working folder and then run it through `MS-DOS` prompt, this should works.

Note that `%1` should be your `TeX file name`, no need to give the extension here